# Selenium WebDriver- Java- It is not willing to click a link

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried, quite a lot and I am not even getting any sort of errors but it is not printing anything (I want it to print the title of the page)

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='Alerts.htm']"));
element.click();
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Here is the HTML code (the part I wish to click), there is a title for both , the page I want to click and the current page.

```
<li title="Alerts"><a href="file:///C:/Users/Sanya/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/Alerts.htm" onclick="setTimeout(showLoading, 50);"><span>Alerts</span></a></li>
```

I am not any errors but it should print the title, which it is not doing.

I have followed many sorts of instructions found here and on the web.

Things I have tried so far:

```
By locator = By.xpath("//li[@title='Alerts']/a");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
element.click();


 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Alert"));
 element.click();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of an HTML document is defined within a `<title>` tag, typically in the `<head>` section.

This is the title that the `getTitle` method returns.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp.

Comment: Yes, I know that but the console is not showing me the title

Comment: You don't seem to have a `<title>` tag in your document (`<li title="Alerts">` is a `<li>` tag with a `title` attribute).

Comment: Oh, no its just a PART of the file. Here is the title, <title>FireEye - FireEye Dashboard</title>

Comment: Well, then I suggest that you provide the HTML of **both** documents (before the click and after the click).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of this. But I think HTMLUnitDriver is a headless browser instance. Kindly try in another browser, firefox perhaps.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You **first** need to open a page in a browser!

```
WebDriver driver = new ...
driver.get(url)    // THIS LAUNCHES AN ACTUAL BROWSER
// now you can actually do things
driver.findElement ...
driver.getTitle()
driver.quit()      // TO DISMISS THE BROWSER
```